# what does core mean in iphone libraries?

Tags: iphone

There's Core Data, Core Audio, Core Animation, etc... does core just mean that it's the basic library of that whole general category?

Comment: It is mostly marketing, probably coming from CoreServices and CoreFoundation frameworks. You can think of them as high-level frameworks that do... (Data, Audio, etc.)

Comment: Core sometimes means C instead of Objective-C, like CoreFoundation vs Foundation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the naming that Apple used to indicate their purpose built libraries.

Nothing special, just marketing really. It sounds a lot better to say they have "CoreData" than "a new data library".